# How many fringes can pass by on a Michaelson interferometer?

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry

A Michaelson interferometer is an instrument that most physics undergrads get to play with once or twice.

[image]

A beam splitter sends part of the light to each of two mirrors, the light returns, then hits an observation screen. And a lovely interference pattern is seen.

One of the fondly recalled exercises from my undergrad was to place a cell in one arm of the system. This cell had glass ends, and a fixture out of which all of the air could be pumped. By counting the fringes that moved by between the vacuum state and normal atmospheric pressure, we were able to infer the index of refraction of air. So many wavelengths change due to the air, inferred to represent the increased optical path length due to the index of refraction.

There are several experiments that have the same basic idea of counting fringes as they move by.  There are keen things to do such as the [Fizeau experiment.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment) (Though you might need a few extra mirrors to make that one work correctly.)

**How many fringes can be observed to pass by** under such conditions of changing the optical path length of one arm? Or, to put it another way, what is the maximum difference in the length of arms that can still produce a clean interference pattern?

I ask this because it means that photons must be, in some sense, that long along their flight path. A photon can interfere with itself even when one path is several wavelengths longer than the other. So it must overlap itself even when one component had a several-wavelengths longer path to travel. I am supposing there is some limit beyond which no fringes are observed. To put in an extreme example, if one arm of the system was some ridiculous amount longer, say several light minutes, then we could have long since observed the light from one side before the other got there.

Comment: LIGO (detection of gravity waves) is the farthest I know at 4km to measure interference.

Comment: @PhysicsDave That is the length of one arm, no? Not the difference between one arm and the other. Unless I am completely misinformed about LIGO, which is certainly possible.

Comment: Not sure of all the LIGO details .... probably have 2 arms as you show .... BUT it is not really the difference that matters, for photons it is about which path length is most favourable, interference an old classical idea .... photons never cancel each other ..... as you say they determine there own path (interfere with themselves is 1930s Dirac ... brilliant but out of date).  So the rings/fringes change as photons prefer arm 1 vs arm 2 .... if arm 2 changes distance by 10 lambda we will see 10 fringe changes.

Comment: @PhysicsDave  Um... Young's single photon double-slit experiment. Yes, photons interfere with themselves.

Comment: Photons interfering with themselves .... or better said "each photon determines its own path"  Richard Feynman.  The EM field directs everything.

Answer (score 0):

When we think of photons we typically think of the energy transfer from one atom to another over any distance, ....however we can can also think of virtual photons which are the force carriers (not energy) in the EM field.

When we say photons interfere with themselves another interpretation is that  their paths have been predetermined by the EM field, especially all the virtual forces due to charges and charge imbalances from excited atoms/molecules.

From the Feynman path integral we can calculate probable pathways .... the integral's solution shows that resonant pathways (i.e paths of lengths of multiples of the wavelength) are most likely.

A final consideration is that because we are dealing with very small dimensions and vibration/movement is very difficult to minimize over great distances.  As an example The LIGO uses "interference" at a distance of 4km.

Answer (score 0):

When a beam travels it diverges. This means that the outer edge of the beam must travel a greater distance to reach the screen than the center of the beam. This creates a beam profile of an arc, like this )  As the difference in arm length increases the difference in divergence becomes greater. This causes the interference rings to become more numerous with less contrast between them. There is no specific distant where they stop. They just slowly fade away as they become more numerous.